# App doesnt show up in the google play store for Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-play

I know this question has been asked many times, I tried to apply all the fixes from the other similar questions, still cant seem to make the app work in the Nexus 7 Tab and works only on phones. Here is the Manifest I use for the free app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.&&&&%%$%#.*****"
android:versionCode="8"
android:versionName="1.7">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>


<!-- android:debuggable should be set false for the google store apk -->
<application
    android:name="com.$%#$%#$%#$%.app.@#$@#$@"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@!#@$@#@"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.@#$@#$@#$" >
    <activity
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:name="com.*#$#*$.app.activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@#$@#$@#$@#$"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- this needs to be set 1 if this is a new app, otherwise set it to the db version that was in CopyDatabaseHelper or increase it by one if you want to update the DB -->
        <meta-data android:name="dbVersion" android:value="4" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
</application>
```

As you can see, I added the compatible screens, also for Nexus 7, changed permission for camera to as Feature. Although one small thing is that, whether my app got screened through the playstore because the permissions were not removed but commented out.

EDIT - I do not have a screenshot for 7 inch or 10 inch Tablet in the developer console, would that be an issue?

EDIT 2 - Clearly adding the screenshots dint help.

EDIT 3 - Edited the Manifest with the current I deployed for testing reasons. I found out that this app doesnt support "Nexus 7 - tilapia" and "Nexus 7 - grouper". I am now trying to figure out why it doesnt support these. Even specifying that camera as a feature is a problem when I dont exclude other camera related stuffs like autofocus and front camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its blatantly because you have `compatible-screens` and the Nexus 7, although you have "defined" it , is not registering.

Is it neccessary for this section at all? And if so, triple check, you have valid parameters for the nexus 7.

I can guarantee removing that section will fix the issue.

According to the docs, `xxhdpi` doesnt exist, so you type in `480` instead. But ive no idea why you have typed in `213` for the nexus.

Reading the android Docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

> Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using
>   this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your
>   application, by not allowing users to install your application if they
>   have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed.
>   You should use it only as a last resort, when the application
>   absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead
>   of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting
>   Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens
>   using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and
>   densities.

Is it really manditory to stop small screens installing your app..

Comment: I agree this is most likely the issue +1

Comment: I did not have the "compatible-screens" before, it was added later in an desperate attempt. When I launch the app from android studio directly into the Nexus 7, the app works all fine. Although after publishing, when I search for the app in the Nexus 7, play store it doesnt show up.

Comment: @vickzzzzz There is only one other obvious device requirement, the camera, but it is set to `required=false`. Launching from studio makes no difference. Google Play will filter out your device if its not compatible. Try going to google play on chrome. It should show your device in a list (if logged in) and tell you its not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes screenshot is the only issue. You need 2 min screenshot to be added on Developer console to visible for respective inch devices.

Comment: If that was the issue, that would be terrible mistake from my end. I already updated screenshots recently. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Nope.. thats not it.. Have screenshots, still the app doesnt show up in the Nexus 7 play store

Comment: I have same issue on my Nexus 7 Tab. My app which is designed for Tabs is not visible on 7 inch Nexus Tab in Google Play store app. But it is showing on 10 inch Tab. I added 7 inch screenshots also but had no luck. What could be the reason?

Comment: @SANTHOSH, We need to add some usage-feature node with false value. It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the Nexus 7 is an xxhdpi device and so could it be because you have not supported your drawables in xxhdpi? I can't imagine why this would prevent it from showing up in the Play store, but it could cause problems.

Also how long ago did you publish the app? It can take several hours for it to show across all devices.